# Firebase DB : How to get data update timestamp?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am using Firebase DB in my mobile app which works absolutely fine. The data is stored in the local device when there's no internet connection and it is pushed automatically to the server when internet connection is available. Everything is working just fine. Now, I would want to store the timestamp when data is updated. Question is how do I do that ?
Scenario : It's 9 o'clock in the morning. User is offline. He/she does something in the app. Data is stored in the device. At 10:00 am, user is in the internet zone. Data is pushed to firebase server. Now, I want both the timestamps in the db i.e. 9:00:00 and 10:00:00.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `{'.sv': 'timestamp'}` as value and the server will replace it by the server time the record was added to the database.

You can use `myField.val() == now` in `database.rules` to ensure no custom value was stored instead.

Comment: I went with {'.sv': 'timestamp'} and it works. Thanks, Günter !

Comment: There is `ServerValue.timestamp` that you can use instead. It was added a while ago https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/4d702ad711f014760434122ce2bd06d2f41b5c6c/packages/firebase_database/lib/src/database_reference.dart#L205